# What deteriorates engine coolant, Milage, age or both?

Tags: engine, coolant, cooling-system, wear

Basically what is said in the title, what is a bigger factor on the life of engine coolant? Is it mileage or age?

Say someone were to cover around 30,000 miles a year however only changed his/her coolant once a year would this be bad practice? they say anti-freeze is good for up to five years but i know most people don't get through around 150,000 miles in five years so...

Well I say five years it seems some manufacturers like to toss a coin on the matter, i read that Hyundai recommend every 30,000 however ford say every 100,000 miles or ten years, surly there is not anti-freeze out there that lasts ten years?

Comment: Actually, there is antifreeze which is [good for the life of the engine](http://www.evanscoolant.com/products/high-performance-coolant/). Albeit, Evans isn't a "stock" coolant, but that's there claim.

Answer (score 3):

You have not given much details about a specific vehicle, so this is a rather general answer.

It is actually both age and mileage. Coolant can last a very long time as provided the cooling system stays intact; i.e. free of contaminants. If the coolant is in good condition, a hydrometer testing indicates the freeze point is within specifications and the engine operates at normal temperatures, there is no reason to change it more frequent than the manufacturer's recommendation.

Speaking of manufacturer's recommendation, that should always be the first consideration because **it is vehicle specific**. Some manufactures recommend initial change at a very high mileage, some as high as 150,000 miles. After the initial change, some recommend more frequent service.

Primary factors to coolant breakdown are going to be driving conditions, mileage, type of coolant, and condition of the cooling system.